# Can "to the park" be added to "I take a walk"?

Tags: prepositions

I think "take" is not a word for movement. Can I say "I take a walk, to the park"? It literally means I walk, to the park.

> take: something used with nouns to say that somebody is doing
> something, performing an action, etc.

Comment: Take a walk, take a stroll, take a run (at something), take a step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with using a prepostional phrase like "to the park" to "I take a walk".

In the non-idiomatic use of "take", "I take the dog to the park",  the word take means to "move something or someone from one place to another".  It is a verb of motion in this sense.

But "take a walk" is an idiomatic phrase, and clearly indicates a motion, so it is very natural to add "to the park" to indicate the destination of the walk.